# How to connect a mediastream to a pannernode using Livekit for WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-audio-api, livekit

I need to connect the mediastream of the track provided to the pannerNode so i can have 3d spatial audio , but something doesnt seem to work.

This is the function:

```
async function handleTrackSubscribed(  //SIMPLE

    track: RemoteTrack,
    publication: RemoteTrackPublication,
    participant: RemoteParticipant
) {
    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
        //const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

        if (track.mediaStream) {

            //audioElement.autoplay = true;
            //audioElement.srcObject = track.mediaStream;

            const panner = new PannerNode(audioContext, {
                panningModel: "HRTF",
                distanceModel: "linear",
                positionX: window.innerWidth /2,
                positionY: window.innerHeight / 2,
                positionZ: 300,
                orientationX: 0.0,
                orientationY: 0.0,
                orientationZ: -1.0,
                refDistance: 1,
                maxDistance: 20_000,
                rolloffFactor: 10,
                coneInnerAngle: 40,
                coneOuterAngle: 50,
                coneOuterGain: 0.4,
            });

            panner.connect(audioContext.destination);

            const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(track.mediaStream);
            audioSource.connect(panner);

            
            // const audioBuffer = await loadAudioBuffer('/sound/song.mp3');
            // const sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            // sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;

            // sourceNode.connect(panner);

            // sourceNode.start();


            const audioForm = document.getElementById('audioForm') as HTMLFormElement;
            const moveButton = document.getElementById('moveButton') as HTMLButtonElement;

            moveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const xValue = parseFloat((document.getElementById('xValue') as HTMLInputElement).value);
                const yValue = parseFloat((document.getElementById('yValue') as HTMLInputElement).value);
                const zValue = parseFloat((document.getElementById('zValue') as HTMLInputElement).value);
        
                panner.positionX.value = xValue;
                panner.positionY.value = yValue;
                panner.positionZ.value = zValue;
            });

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are some parts commented , the first 3 lines commented are creating an audio element directly in the html , if i do that the audio works perfectly fine , but i cant have 3d, but it works so the stream is there.
The second commented part is literally a song i imported to test the panner and the panner works perfectly fine , so the conclusion is that the mistake is in connecting the stream to the panner, but i dont know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're testing this in Chrome. In this case the `MediaStream` coming from WebRTC needs to be connected to a media element even if you don't intend to play it.

Uncommenting `audioElement.srcObject = track.mediaStream` without setting `autoplay` to `true` or calling `play()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

```js
const mediaStream = new MediaStream(track.mediaStream);
const options = {
    mediaStream: mediaStream,
  };
const sourceNode = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(audioContext, options)

sourceNode.connect(panner).connect(audioContext.destination);

//audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);

if(track instanceof RemoteAudioTrack) {
    track.setWebAudioPlugins([panner])
    console.log("RemoteTrack")
}
```

Comment: great that you got it to work, as context you could add to your answer that users have to enable the webAudioMix in the RoomOptions for this to work